# easy firewall ufw settings for a beginner coming from windows

Tags: security, firewall, ufw, gufw

I am used to firewall on windows. everything is allowed and new apps have to ask for permission.

when I look at current connections in settings' firewall tab, only a few have program names associated with them. so I must allow connection by default.

how do I set my ufw like windows?

I am sure I need a few things like 1. allow things to be fine by default. 2. block malicious stuff like samba advertising you on public networks. 3. does programs open their own ports cause i heard ubuntu does not open ports by default.

if you read up to this point, you realize i know nothing about ufw, so please help.

EDIT: i use jammy. i use it as everyday desktop. I am okay with most apps running but I want to be able to block apps I know I dont trust connecting to internet and auto-block malicious stuff.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1442392/edit) and add which version of Ubuntu you are using. What do you use it for? Do you use it to run any servers? If so which ones? If you use Ubuntu for "normal" desktop uses you don't need ufw. You can enable it with `sudo ufw enable` and have the peace of mind. If ufw blocks something search how to open the port that needs to be opened, based on which service is blocked.

Comment: I edited it my comment

Comment: yes mostly it does thanks

Comment: Also take a look at [As a new Ubuntu desktop 18.04 LTS user, do I need to use ufw for a firewall or is iptables sufficient?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126196/as-a-new-ubuntu-desktop-18-04-lts-user-do-i-need-to-use-ufw-for-a-firewall-or-i)

Answer (score 0):

I indicate Gufw, the graphical interface of ufw because it is easy to configure and use, Gufw allows users to create rules, manage usage profiles for the tool, turn on or off the firewall, have access to logs and monitor the behavior of applications in real time, observing which ports each of them access to communicate with the Internet etc.
https://gufw.org/